# how do i replace chunks of a character with a single character

Tags: javascript

So I have a string something like this

`thing       thing2    thing3         thing4`

How do I replace the chunks of spaces with a single character, so the output would be

> thing|thing2|thing3|thing4

The chunks are random length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the regular expression `\s+` to match one or more consecutive whitespace characters and replace them with pipes.

```js
const str = 'thing       thing2    thing3         thing4';
const res = str.replace(/\s+/g, '|');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

You use the string `replace()` method:

```js
var s = 'thing       thing2    thing3         thing4'
s = s.replace(/ +/g, '|');
console.info(s);
```